# How to add rails relationship after the fact?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I've already created my models and have gone through several migrations.  Now, I want to setup `has_many :books` in `Subject` and `belongs_to :subject` in `Book`.  I've added those to the .rb files, but I'm still allowed to save a book with a subject_id that does not exist.  I'm expecting a FK constraint violation.

Must I create a migration file for this?  If so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can generate a lone migration file (without a model) by using `script/generate migration`, or `rails g migration` for rails 2 / 3 respectively. You can then include the constraints to the self.up method in the migration file and run them on the database using a rake db:migrate.

Note however that unless you're planning on handling the error using your own custom code to catch ActiveRecord errors you're probably better off using rails validations to ensure that associations are present. i.e.

app/models/book.rb

```
validates_presence_of :subject
```

**EDIT:** If you want to add foreign keys to your database then you will have to know how to do this using the command set relevant to your database engine (e.g. for MySQL http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html). Since rails is designed to work with databases that don't support foreign keys there are no built in functions in the rails migration toolkit which can help you with this process.

as a rough outline of what you'll need in your migration (using MySQL specific syntax):

```
def self.up
  execute "ALTER TABLE books FOREIGN KEY `my_foreign_key_name` (subject_id) REFERENCES subjects (id)"
end

def self.down
  execute "ALTER TABLE books DROP FOREIGN KEY `my_foreign_key_name`"
end
```

Comment: Thanks.  What would the self.down look like?  I already have these columns present and want to ensure that I can roll back if it does something screwy.

Comment: And, in your answer, are you suggesting both or just the latter?

Comment: There's no harm in doing both, that way if you do end up working directly with your database, or using a different application to access the same data you'll not end up inserting data in a way your rails app might have a problem with. If all you're doing is adding FK constraints to your DB using self.up then i'd suggest that all your self.down method should contain is the code to remove the constraints again.

Comment: The following did not add any FK constraints:  `class BookSubjectRelationship < ActiveRecord::Migration
  class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :subject
  end

  class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :books
  end
  
  def up
  end

  def down
  end
end`

Comment: Ron, I think you're fundamentally misunderstanding the role of a migration. Migrations use their own set of functions to add columns etc to the database. Adding in some ActiveRecord code won't to anything. If you want to add FKs to your database you'll have to use the execute function (see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html) and craft your own SQL code to create the constraints. will edit my  answer to explain what I mean.